# Exjs 4 grid panel with vertical scroll bar issue

Tags: extjs

[image]Vertical scroll bar is taking/overlay's some width from last grid column. And I have implemented the search functionality on grid, then when matched elements are not found in the grid it show's empty grid. But while displaying empty grid all the grid columns are changing the width. someone help me I am new to extjs

Comment: Can you take screenshot of what you are seeing and post here please?

Comment: sorry tell me how to add here image

Comment: You should see the option to add an image if you edit your question, I think you can only do it from the web, not from mobile device though.

Comment: I have tried with the  autoScroll: true, and reserveScrollbar: true, options but not able to set the vertical scroll bar height with grid table height.